# Call erb within an external class in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

What's the correct way to call the erb function (which is available via Sinatra) if I have a helper class outside the Sinatra main application.

For example, I have in my_app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'my_external_class.rb'
get '/' do
   MyExternalClass.some_function(request)
end
```

Then I have a file called: my_external_class.rb

```
class MyExternalClass
  def self.some_function request
    erb :some_template
  end
end
```

When running Sinatra and executing a get request, I get a **undefined method `erb' for MyExternalClass**. I assume I am missing either some require, or maybe I need to pass the Sinatra object to the class (but I don't know how to achieve that).

How could I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a [helpers module](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers) for your methods:

```
# module instead of a class
module MyHelpersModule
  # no need for 'self'
  def some_function(request)
    erb :some_template
  end
end
```

Then in your main app file call `helpers MyHelpersModule`. This will make all the methods in `MyHelpersModule` available in your application and also, since they are executed in the same context, the existing Sinatra methods (like `erb`) will be available to your helpers.

```
require 'sinatra'
require './my_helpers_module'

helpers MyHelpersModule

get '/' do
   some_function(request)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To imitate rendering behavior of Sinatra controller in some other class you can create module like this:

```
module ErbRender

  include Sinatra::Templates
  include Sinatra::Helpers
  include Sinatra::ContentFor

  def settings
    @settings ||= begin
      settings = Sinatra::Application.settings
      settings.root = "#{ROOT}/app"
      settings
    end
  end

  def template_cache
    @template_cache ||= Tilt::Cache.new
  end

end
```

*Here you may need to tune `settings.root`*

Usage example:

```
class ArticleIndexingPostBody

  include ErbRender

  def get_body
    erb :'amp/articles/show', layout: :'amp/layout'
  end

end
```

This will properly render templates with layouts including `content_for`